# Sonarqube .Net Core Global Tool and sonar-project.properties

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube

I am trying to setup a .net core project to use the .Net Core Global tool as mentioned in the guides here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/

And i want it to use my sonar-project.properties file but it seems to be ignoring it. The file is in the same location as my .sln file and i am trying to run sonar with this command in that location as well:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin -k:"project-name" -d:sonar.login="key"
```

here is my sonar-project.properties file:

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.url

sonar.projectKey=project-name

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.verbose=false
sonar.log.level=INFO

sonar.exclusions=\
  **/bin/**/*,\
  **/obj/**/*

sonar.project.baseDir=./
sonar.visualstudio.solution=donet.sln

sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
```

Comment: What makes you think the file is ignored? Do you get any error message?

Comment: See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/1031

Comment: @raspy i was adding a property for sonar.host.url and it was not using it and using localhost instead. I have now found out that this tool doesn't use it and you have to pass everything you want to use via the command line